# Flutter: Tap event on child is propagated to parent

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I have the following widget tree in flutter:
Listener => CustomPaint => GestureDectector => Image.asset.

When I tap on the image the gesture detector picks up the onTap, but also the Listener picks it up.

How to prevent the listener from receiving the event as well?

Comment: Can we see some code as to what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behaviour. Use [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) instead, if possible.

> The child onTap is called, and the parent's is not as the gesture has been consumed.

Comment: Is the same true if they were both listeners?

Comment: Yes that is true.

Comment: I am using a listener on the parent, because I want to capture mouse's secondary button drags. This seems not to be supported by the GestureDetector. Taps with the secondary button are supported, not drag events.